# Number of buttons and event should be in single clicks or method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, window

There is a windows Form with many buttons in it(assume like caliculator) one method should be written to access all the buttons but button click of each and every button shouln't be written can you help me to get solution for this

Comment: Basically just add one button click event handler, and then set all the other button's onclick properties to it. Course how you identify which button was clicked short of testing sender, is another wrinkle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create 1 click handler by double-clicking the 1st button
2. select the 2nd button and open the Events tab in the properties window
3. use the dropdown of the Click event to select the handler from step 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use method purposed by Henk, or you can dig into you form designer code (assume you want to use only Button2 click event):

```
this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button2Click);
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button2Click);
this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button2Click);
```